# Why this IDC script can not find all the functions?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

Test platform is Linux 32 bit, ELF file, GNU coreutils.

Basically I am trying dump all the functions using IDC script, here is part of my IDC script:

```
for (addr = NextFunction(addr); addr != BADADDR; addr = NextFunction(addr)) {
    name = Name(addr);
    end = GetFunctionAttr(addr, FUNCATTR_END);
    locals = GetFunctionAttr(addr, FUNCATTR_FRSIZE);
    frame = GetFrame(addr);
    ret = GetMemberOffset(frame, " r");
    if (ret == -1) continue;
    firstArg = ret + 4;
    args = GetStrucSize(frame) - firstArg;

    dumpFunction(name, addr, end);
}
```

I am using it to test GNU coretuils, and I find some functions like

```
            public qset_acl
            qset_acl        proc near

            jmp     chmod_or_fchmod
            qset_acl        endp
```

which can not be found by this script.

Am I doing something wrong? Could any one give me some help?

Thank you!

Comment: Check the stack frame of that function (CTRL-K) to see if it does in fact define the " r" member, otherwise you will skip it with the `continue` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack frame structure is not created unless necessary (i.e. the function accesses a stack argument or local variable), so these stub functions get skipped by your `(ret == -1)` check.